# How to regroup values with same primary key using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I have a request in Access that is linked to a database.

Let's say, that it tells me which primary key is linked to apples or tomatoes.

RESULTS:

```
0001 Apple  
0001 Tomatoes
0002 Apple 
0003 Tomatoes
```

"0001" likes apple and tomatoes, but Access displayed it on 2 separate lines.

Is there a way to view it on the same line?

Like this :

```
0001 Apple, Tomatoes
0002 Apple
0003 Tomatoes
```

Comment: If you have duplicates it isn't a primary key. There is no built in functionality that I'm aware of that can do what you are asking. You will need to iterate through each record, and with the use of a dictionary, combine each like value into a comma delimited string.

Comment: @Warcupine I would suggest using a collection over a dictionary, simply because keys for collection items must be unique.

Comment: Dictionaries have a ```.exists``` which i prefer to error handling the unique values. Though either works.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box functionality in MS Access which will aggregate records by a given field and concatenate the corresponding field values for another field within each group.

You would need to define a function such as Allen Browne's [ConcatRelated](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) VBA function, which will acquire a recordset for each group and will iterate over the group contents, concatenating the values using a given delimiter.

For your example, this might be:

```
SELECT ID, ConcatRelated("Fruit", "YourTable", "ID = " & [ID])
FROM YourTable
```

Where `YourTable` is the name of your table, `ID` is your integer field by which the results should be grouped, and `Fruit` is your text field to be concatenated.